# Bootstrap 3: How to properly use a form-groups (a form) inside a grid?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a university assessment I have been tasked with creating a very simple website with the concept of a 'Facebook Lite' that uses basic PHP and SQL functionality.

I am very new to bootstrap and have been attempting to correctly align a form within my register page. I can't quite figure out the correct way to place a form within a 3-6-3 bootstrap grid, the webpage just keeps presenting the form incorrectly to how I would like it.

The page I am working with is a php file (register.php) and so far I have worked out how to successfully create a working bootstrap horizontal form that will collapse to vertical when the window is sized down etc.

However I can't quite get it centered, the form keeps presenting to the right of the viewport, and the input boxes look horrible on a mobile device.

As explained I am extremely new to bootstrap so please forgive me if I am going about this the completely wrong way.

For your convenience I have prepared 2 pages;
Page 1 (register.php) -
What I believe to be the correct way to make a simple bootstrap form, however it is not centered and the input boxes go TINY on a mobile device (I just followed the bootstrap website instructions)

http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~s3605062/register.php

Page 2 (register2.php)
My attempt to place my newly created form INSIDE a bootstrap grid of 3-6-3 (to supposedly center the form). I used the example demo from W3Schools so I could try and understand how it works, but as you can see its not working properly...

http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~s3605062/register2.php

Code of register.php:

```php
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/register_new.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="e.g. jsmith@example.com" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Create a password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="e.g. John Smith" name="fullname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="screenname">Screen Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="screenname" placeholder="e.g. John S" name="screenname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dateofbirth"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="nonbinary">Non-Binary</option>
      <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="gender">Status:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="relationship">In a relationship</option>
      <option value="complicated">Its complicated</option>
      <option value="partnership">In a domestic partnership</option>
      <option value="married">Married</option>
      <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
      <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="location">Location:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="e.g. Melbourne, Australia" name="location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="registerbtn" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Code of register2.php:

```php
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">

  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/register_new.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="e.g. jsmith@example.com" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Create a password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="e.g. John Smith" name="fullname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="screenname">Screen Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="screenname" placeholder="e.g. John S" name="screenname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dateofbirth"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="nonbinary">Non-Binary</option>
      <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="gender">Status:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="relationship">In a relationship</option>
      <option value="complicated">Its complicated</option>
      <option value="partnership">In a domestic partnership</option>
      <option value="married">Married</option>
      <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
      <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="location">Location:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="e.g. Melbourne, Australia" name="location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
        <button type="registerbtn" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As an end result I would like it to have the form centered like on register2.php, but with the form labels and inputs presenting properly (similar to how they are on register.php). I am not even sure if a bootstrap grid is the correct way to do this!

Any help is extremely appreciated thank you and I do apologise for the lengthy post I just wanted to explain myself clearly.

Thank you.

Ricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the first code:
Try to always declare row with column inside container. d-flex and justify-content-center will help to centralized the form. It's bootstrap default class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/register_new.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="e.g. jsmith@example.com" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Create a password" name="pwd">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="e.g. John Smith" name="fullname">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="screenname">Screen Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="screenname" placeholder="e.g. John S" name="screenname">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dateofbirth"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="gender">Gender:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
              <option value="nonbinary">Non-Binary</option>
              <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="gender">Status:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Please select...</option>
              <option value="single">Single</option>
              <option value="relationship">In a relationship</option>
              <option value="complicated">Its complicated</option>
              <option value="partnership">In a domestic partnership</option>
              <option value="married">Married</option>
              <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
              <option value="notsharing">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="location">Location:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="e.g. Melbourne, Australia" name="location">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="registerbtn" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the second form default.css, you are using padding for form, that's why you got a blank space in left side.

```
form {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 370px;
  }
```

Thanks.